# Implementing Grover's oracle with multiple solutions in Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit, grovers-algorithm, oracles

I want to turn a state

$$
|\Psi_1⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(|000⟩+|001⟩+|010⟩+|011⟩+|100⟩+|101⟩+|110⟩+|111⟩)
$$

into

$$
|\Psi_2⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(|000⟩+|001⟩+|010⟩+|011⟩+|100⟩-|101⟩-|110⟩+|111⟩)
$$

using a phase oracle before applying Grover's amplification.

One example from [Qiskit's official page for Grover's Algorithm](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/grover.html) does this by manually building a circuit with Controlled-Z gates, but [another Qiskit document](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/algorithms/07_grover.html) simply uses a class *Statevector.from_label* to mark the target state $|11⟩$ without constructing a circuit, which I assume can only assign single state.

Having the desired states in a form of Python list, i.e. `[101, 110]`, can I directly convert this into a phase oracle that does the intended job in Qiskit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve that, my favorite is probably this one: The oracle you describe above is just a classical function ("True if my bitstring is 101 or 110") converted to a quantum phase flip. So essentially you only have to build a circuit that implements that classical logic plus some gates to do the phase flip.

### Option A: Via classical logic

Step 1: Create the classical logic circuit in Qiskit:

```
from qiskit.circuit import classical_function, Int1

# define a classical function that can be turned into a circuit
@classical_function
def oracle(x1: Int1, x2: Int1, x3: Int1) -> Int1:
    return (x1 and not x2 and x3) or (x1 and x2 and not x3)

bitcircuit = oracle.synth()  # turn it into a circuit
```

Now you have something looking like this:

```
q_0: ──■────■──
       │    │
q_1: ──■────┼──
       │    │
q_2: ──┼────■──
     ┌─┴─┐┌─┴─┐
q_3: ┤ X ├┤ X ├
     └───┘└───┘
```

It flips the output bit (the one at the bottom) if the qubits are in state $|101\rangle$ or $|110\rangle$.

Step 2: To change this into a phaseflip oracle you can sandwich the bottom qubit in between X and H gates:

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit

phaseoracle = QuantumCircuit(4)
phaseoracle.x(3)
phaseoracle.h(3)
phaseoracle.compose(bitoracle, inplace=True)
phaseoracle.h(3)
phaseoracle.x(3)
```

to get this circuit, which implements your oracle:

```
q_0: ────────────■────■────────────
                 │    │
q_1: ────────────■────┼────────────
                 │    │
q_2: ────────────┼────■────────────
     ┌───┐┌───┐┌─┴─┐┌─┴─┐┌───┐┌───┐
q_3: ┤ X ├┤ H ├┤ X ├┤ X ├┤ H ├┤ X ├
     └───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘
```

So all together:

```
from qiskit.circuit import classical_function, Int1, QuantumCircuit

# define a classical function that can be turned into a circuit
@classical_function
def oracle(x1: Int1, x2: Int1, x3: Int1) -> Int1:
    return (x1 and not x2 and x3) or (x1 and x2 and not x3)

bitcircuit = oracle.synth()  # turn it into a circuit


phaseoracle = QuantumCircuit(4)
phaseoracle.x(3)
phaseoracle.h(3)
phaseoracle.compose(bitoracle, inplace=True)
phaseoracle.h(3)
phaseoracle.x(3)
```

### Option B: Via looking hard

You could see that the oracle is implemented by two controlled Z gates:

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit

phaseoracle = QuantumCircuit(3)
phaseoracle.cz(0, 2)
phaseoracle.cz(0, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. So I presume it is possible to use Option A to implement an oracle for Grover's max/min search as well? Something like "true if this bitstring's decimal value is above the given threshold".

Comment: Not yet! Right now it just supports operations on binary values (`not and or ^ (xor)`). But support for integer valued operations (like `>`) can be added in future.

Comment: Is there any benefit in using method B over method A ?

Comment: Yes, it uses one less qubit :)

Comment: @Cryoris I See. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for **classical logic**.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be using CLASS *Grover* from `qiskit.aqua.algorithms`.

As you can see in this [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.algorithms.Grover.html), the parameter `oracle` of `Grover` can take one of the following forms, a `QuantumCircuit`, an `Oracle`, or a `Statevector`. Now as you've already found out by yourself, `Statevector.from_label('..')` accepts a single label.

For multiple states, you can simply prepare a list representing your chosen states and pass it to `Statevector()` in this way:

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import Grover


good_state = ['110','101']
oracle = Statevector([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0])
grover = Grover(oracle=oracle, good_state=good_state)
my_gate=grover.grover_operator.to_gate()
```

Comment: You might ask why $list=[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]$? Let's say you have 3 bits here, and you want $′101′$(=5) and $′110′$(=6). If you generate all possible bit-strings with 3 bits you'll have $′000′,′001′....′111′$ and you can easily see your target bit-strings are the **6**th and **7**th. Hence the **6**th (5+1) and **7**th (6+1) elements in the $list$ are 1.